# Cloning git repository from svn repository, results in file-less, remote-branch-less git repo

Tags: git, repository, git-svn, git-clone

### Working SVN repo

I'm starting a git repo to interact with a svn repo.  The svn repository is set and working fine, with a single commit of a basic README file in it.

Checking it out works fine:

```
tchalvak:~/test/svn-test$ 
svn checkout --username=myUsernameHere http://www.url.to/project/here/charityweb/
A    charityweb/README
Checked out revision 1.
```

### Failed git-svn clone of svn repo

When I try to clone the repository in git, the first step shows no errors...

```
tchalvak:~/test$ 
git svn clone -s --username=myUserNameHere http://www.url.to/project/here/charityweb/
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/tchalvak/test/charityweb/.git/
Authentication realm: <http://www.url.to/project/here:80> Charity Web
Password for 'myUserNameHere':
```

...but results in a useless folder, containing no files, no branches, and no commits:

```
tchalvak:~/test$ ls
charityweb
tchalvak:~/test$ cd charityweb/
tchalvak:~/test/charityweb$ ls
tchalvak:~/test/charityweb$ ls -al
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 tchalvak tchalvak 4096 2010-04-02 13:46 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 tchalvak tchalvak 4096 2010-04-02 13:46 ..
drwxr-xr-x 8 tchalvak tchalvak 4096 2010-04-02 13:47 .git
tchalvak:~/test/charityweb$ git branch -av
tchalvak:~/test/charityweb$ git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
tchalvak:~/test/charityweb$ git fetch
fatal: Where do you want to fetch from today?
tchalvak:~/test/charityweb$ git rebase origin/master
fatal: bad revision 'HEAD'
fatal: Needed a single revision
invalid upstream origin/master
tchalvak:~/test/charityweb$ git log
fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'
```

How do I get something I can commit back to?  I expect I'm doing something wrong in this process, but what?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You used the `-s` option to `git svn clone`, but from your example, it doesn't appear that  your Subversion repository is using the standard layout (*i.e.*, trunk, branches, and tags directories at the repository root).

If that's the case, clone without `-s`.

Comment: Thanks, that did indeed solve it, it's been a while since I worked with svn, so I didn't realize that the README being at the root was indicative of a repository layout that was non-standard.  Should have realized, glad you did.